# Detecting when a control is added to the page JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've been instructed to add a script to a page that launches a chat widget. I have no control over the script as it's a `<script src='urlHere'`> that is open to change.

The widget requests a users name and email before they can chat and I need to pre-populate these fields. The problem is I can't detect when the widget is loaded to hook into it's controls.

I was thinking `setInterval()` until I get a hit on the widgets controls or is there a better way?

```
setInterval(1000, function (){  
    if ($('.control').length){
    // It's loaded
    }
});
```

Comment: Assuming this is a third-party script which you have no control over, use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Although note that if their JS create a cross-domain iframe, what you're trying to do will not be possible.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, there's no iframe. All the controls are on my side so looks like that will do :)